# 18.04: Different IP addresses found with IP lookup command line

Tags: ip, ifconfig

I am doing the following from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.208.65  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 172.17.208.79
        ether 00:15:5d:c0:71:38  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.120.0.134  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 10.120.0.135
        ether 00:ff:e2:51:de:11  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.75.1  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 10.0.75.15
        ether 00:15:5d:25:96:00  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0xfe<compat,link,site,host>
        loop  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wifi0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.68  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 60:03:08:9b:2c:d2  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0
```

and:

```
curl ifconfig.me
xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

why do the IP's do not match, shouldn't eth0 and/or wifi0 be the same as ifconfig.me?

Comment: That's because you are connected to some router with NAT.

Answer (score 2):

No, `ethX` ot `wifi` shouldn't always match `curl ifconfig.me`.

The `71.19.252.146` is your real internet address, but `10.x.x.x` addresses are local.

You are connected to some router (local or ISP managed) that translates addresses using [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).